# How to check if Flash is installed?

Tags: android, flash

i'm using this snippet to check if an app/activity is installed:

```
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}

public static boolean isScanAvailable(Context context) {
    return isIntentAvailable(context, "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
}
```

In the above example it checks if the Barcode Scanner App is installed, which works just fine.
However, if i try to check for the Adobe Flashplayer using `com.adobe.flashplayer` it doesn't work and always returns false.

Is there a better / more reliable method to check for Flash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uhm yeah. My code posted above does Intent checking which isn't working for the flashplayer (no public intents i guess).

The more obvious way would be to just use `getPackageInfo()` which works just fine:

```
    public static boolean isFlashAvailable(Context context) {
    String mVersion;
    try {
        mVersion = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.adobe.flashplayer", 0).versionName;
          Log.d("Flash", "Installed: " + mVersion);
          return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
          Log.d("Flash", "Not installed");
          return false;
    }
   }
```

(As an added bonus we get the exact version number too)