# Android 2.2 phones without Adobe Flash support

Tags: android, flash, android-2.2-froyo

Where can I get a definitive list of Android 2.2+ phones that don't support Flash?

I released an app that uses Flash for some features if installed on Android 2.2+ phones, but found out today from a user that the T-Mobile MyTouch 3G has 2.2 but can't get Flash.  At this point I'm going in and adding a check against the Build.MODEL for the MyTouch 3G but I'd like to know if there are other phones I should check for as well.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how small is the percentage of users which are using custom Android 2.2 builds without flash on their rooted devices, but are you sure you want to exclude them from using your app?

Small percentage of a big number can still be a big number.

Here is a thread on [how to check if Flash is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458930/how-to-check-if-flash-is-installed).

Comment: Yeah I already know how to check if flash is installed.  What I want is a list of specific phone models that have 2.2 or greater but don't support flash.