# How to launch another application without knowing its class name or package name?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two questions.

1. I have an .apk but I don't know anything about the class name or package name. Is there any possibility to find the class name and the package name?
2. If I don't get the class name or the package name of the application, will I be able to launch the application from my current application?

Comment: What kind of application are we talking about? A pre-installed one?

Answer (score 1):

No you won't be able to launch it without knowing the class name. You can use [APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to disassemble the APK file. When you do this, it will show you the android manifest file for that apk. In the manifest XML, you will see declarations of the package name and specific process/activity names you can directly launch/reference. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914663/how-to-check-if-the-flash-players-is-installed-on-android) also has references + more specifics on this process + what to look for in the manifest.

Comment: Also the answer I referenced shows how to check and see if the program/service/activity you are referencing is installed, which you're going to need to know if you want to make an app that is dependent on another.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [decompile the apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode) and then the source code is quite readable. From there you should be able to detect the package and class name of the activity you want to start.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after installing the application, when i went into data/data folder i found the package name of the installed apk.

I found the class name by extracting the package and reading the manifest file. :)