# Notify user if flash player is not installed on his android device

Tags: android, flash

I need to ask user to install flash player, when he install my apps in his android phone and flash player is not already installed, how can I do this with coding ???

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try trough Javacode :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.adobe.flashplayer", "com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashExpandableFileChooser"));
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (activities != null && activities.size() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash is installed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Reference : [How to check if the Flash players is installed on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914663/how-to-check-if-the-flash-players-is-installed-on-android/4914821#4914821)