# how to load swf files without using webview

Tags: android, flash

Is there any way to load the swf files directly without use of webview..

Now i am trying to run swf files using webview but the swf file is very slow on device.

In short according to my procedure the flash file running on android device and tablet is very slow as compared to if i view this on my desktop pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a standalone flash player for Android. But even if there was it would mean that people need to install that first before starting your app.

I believe the slowness you experience as nothing to do with webviews but simply with the resources available on a mobile device (1/3rd minimum of the cpu device and 1/10th of the memory).

You can check if that is the case by simply trying to launch your swf from the native web browser of your device and see if its better. If not, the problem is really your device.

You will probably need to create a strip down version of your flash for mobile devices.

Beside you should know that adobe plans to stop flash for mobile devices : http://www.fiercemobilecontent.com/story/adobe-confirms-flash-support-android-ice-cream-sandwich/2011-11-21

Good luck

Comment: in (samsung glaxy tab) android flash player is already installed. so how to open my swf files directly my code. because i have flash player installed in it

Comment: I have a galaxy tab too and I'm pretty sure there is no stand alone Flash player. Only the plugin to the web browser. So I don't know of an intent you could pass to start the player. You can dig here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914663/how-to-check-if-the-flash-players-is-installed-on-android